# Saving field value. Does not show current value in grid

Tags: javascript, save, field

With the help of members here in the community I made a javascript code that calculates fields in array and shows the result in another field. It worked very well.
My problem is that I have to click 2X on the upgrade button for the correct result to appear on the grid. Attached image. I need help resolving this. Thank you all.

[image]

```
function render_field( $field ) {
        ?>
<label for="total">Total:</label>
<input class="total" id="total" name="<?php echo esc_attr($field['name']) ?>">

<style>
.total { 
font-size:18px !important;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
let total = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]').forEach(el=>total+=+el.value);
document.querySelector('#total').value = total;
console.log(total);
</script>
        <?php
    }
}
// create field
new acf_field_sum();
```

Comment: Where is your upgrade button click handler, I don't see it in the code you posted

Comment: @CertainPerformance is the native WordPress button ... does this help?